# self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.slide.load_next(mode="next") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am new to python and just trying to use some of the concepts but is unable to resolve this error, I am not getting that why my code is showing error is something I had done wrong in the code,

I am runnning this login file with two of the functions of customer_page class, please help me out

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
import customer

Window.size = (350, 580)

class LoginPage(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("home_page.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("reg_customer.kv"))
        cus = customer.customer_page()
        cus.next()
        cus.next1()
        return screen_manager

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.login, 3)


    def login(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = "main"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginPage().run()
```

customer.py file :-

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (350, 580)



class Customer_page(MDApp):

    def next(self):
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.info.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.progress.value = 100
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.icon.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.icon.icon = "check-decagram"

    def next1(self):
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.address.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.progress1.value = 100
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.icon1.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.icon1.icon = "check-decagram"

   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    customer_page().run()
```

my console is giving this error again and again

```
File "C:\Users\reals\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sample.py", line 21, in build
     cus.next()
   File "C:\Users\reals\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\customer.py", line 18, in next
     self.root.get_screen('customer').ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
```

Comment: Your `Customer_page` has no `root` defined, which causes the error. And unless you are doing something very unusual, you should not have two `MDApp` objects in the same App.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow shourya. When providing a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), don't forget to add placeholders for your files. For example: "home_page.kv" could not be found, and I can't reproduce it because I don't know what it contains. When people can copy/paste your code example and run it, it makes it easy and quick to help you.  Don't hesitate to make your example code as small as possible so we can focus on your problem. Otherwise, this is a good question! Well done!